# Can suspend happens in coroutine randomly by OS, even if we do not perform delay function explicitly?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I have the following code

```
val atomicInteger = AtomicInteger(1)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val singleThreadDispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()

    // 1st launch
    lifecycleScope.launch(singleThreadDispatcher) {
        val value = atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()
        //
        // Can suspend like delay ever happen at this point, by OS randomly, before logging?
        //
        Log.i("DEBUG", "value = ${value}")
    }

    // 2nd launch
    lifecycleScope.launch(singleThreadDispatcher) {
        val value = atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()
        //
        // Can suspend like delay ever happen at this point, by OS randomly, before logging?
        //
        Log.i("DEBUG", "value = ${value}")
    }

    // 3rd launch
    lifecycleScope.launch(singleThreadDispatcher) {
        val value = atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()
        //
        // Can suspend like delay ever happen at this point, by OS randomly, before logging?
        //
        Log.i("DEBUG", "value = ${value}")
    }
}
```

The following output is always being logged.

```
1
2
3
```

I was wondering, is there any chance, where suspend happens in coroutine randomly by OS, even if we do not perform `delay` function explicitly?

For example, in **2nd launch**, can suspend happens after `atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()` and before `Log.i`, which can cause the following output being produced

```
1
3
2
```

Is the above outcome ever possible in the above code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coroutines in Kotlin are scheduled cooperatively. That means they have to yield the control by themselves, nobody can suspend, stop or kill them externally. OS can put an underlying thread to sleep, but if resumed, it will continue with the same coroutine.

On the other hand, coroutines generally try to be cooperative and yield often. Every suspension point is a potential place where the current coroutine could give control to another coroutine. If we write a CPU-intensive algorithm which never suspends, we are encouraged to [yield](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html) manually from time to time to not occupy the thread entirely.

In your specific case it is guaranteed a coroutine won't suspend between `getAndIncrement()` and `Log.i()`. It is guaranteed to get a 1, 2, 3 result. However, the execution order of each `launch()` block is not guaranteed.

Comment: If, in between `getAndIncrement()` and `Log.i()`, a function which marked with `suspend` keyword is called, does that mean 1,3,2 can possible happen? If a function without `suspend` keyword is called, does that also mean 1,2,3 is guaranteed? Thanks.

Comment: Yes and yes. Every time we call a `suspend` function, we should expect it could suspend and pass control to another coroutine. And if we call a non-suspend function, we should be safe. I can imagine a potential corner case where a non-suspend function passes the control back to the same dispatcher, and then to another coroutine. But this is a very exotic case and shouldn't generally happen. Maybe if e.g. using `runBlocking()` inside another one.

Comment: Even though it is true that avoiding calling any suspend functions will guarantee the coroutine will not suspend between two calls in your coroutine, I would not recommend trying to build an orderly queue of work this way. It's kind of a fragile hack--you could accidentally call a suspend function and it's not obvious this would break your code. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you may want to consider using Mutexes, Semaphores, Channels, and/or lazy Jobs to control execution order.